# кластерный индекс некластерный индекс

Tags: sql-server

> Если у таблицы есть кластерный индекс, то есть мы повесили некластерный индекс на кластерную таблицу, то row локатером будет ключ кластерного индекса.
>   То есть находим некластерный индекс, по некластерному индексу находим кластерный индекс, по кластерному индексу находим все необходимые данные.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как найти некластерный индекс? И если такой индекс найден, то может ли в нем содержатся указатель на другой некластерный индекс или только на кластерный?

Comment: "то row локатером будет ключ кластерного индекса" - это означает что ВСЕГДА некластерный индекс указывает на кластерный и никак иначе. Т.е. некластерный не может указывать на другой некластрный, т.к. это не имеет смысла

Comment: А вопрос про "как найти некластерный" не понятен. Вы сами создаете нужные индексы. А БД при выполнении запроса использует тот, который посчитает наиболее подходящим

Comment: Да сколько можно! Вы уже создали 6 (!) тем про одно и то же! меньше чем за сутки...